# Task Scheduler does not run bat file at the bat file's location

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, task-scheduler

I am running a server and I'm intending to run a .bat file on startup. However, when it runs, it cannot read the files from its original location.

Heres a better explanation:

The .bat file runs "spigot.jar" (in the same folder) which will run the server.
spigot.jar will check eula.txt in the same file to do some checks before starting up the server.

For the .bat file, I put the location of the file (the "c:\users...") and it runs correctly when I click on it.

However in Task Scheduler when it runs the .bat file it seems to not be able to access or read the eula.txt and says "please read the eula.txt file and put true in it"

Comment: You should not use relative paths in scripts meant to run remotely or without an interactive session. Use properly configured paths, and possibly the Path statement, to make it run properly.

Comment: *For the .bat file, I put the location of the file* Add `ChDir /D` to this location in front of your script.

Comment: The current dir is not necessarily the one your batch file resides in. To ***force*** the current dir to batch files location, insert as 2nd line to the batch `CD /D "%~0"` or `PushD "%~0"`

Comment: Correction, should be `CD /D "%~dp0"` or `PushD "%~dp0"`

Comment: @LotPings Thank you! Adding CD /D "%~dp0" on the second line works!